# Can't dynamically set afterSelectionChange of ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Is there a way to change the afterSelectionChange property dynamically.

In my project I am having one ng-grid that is being filled  with different data . I had managed to change the grid data and columnDef dynamically . But I am not able to change the afterSelectionChange property . Please help !!!

Comment: there is no way changing dynamically afterSelectionChange property, but may be there is another way to accomplish your task? can you tell what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to call a seperate function to be called when the grid entity is clicked .  The grid may have different data , and each time its called different function .

Comment: well, it's not the best design but you can always use some switch statement in your main function and call the appropriate function.

Comment: Whats the best design den ???